# MySQL query to fetch records using LIMIT as dynamic value from column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "tbl_shop" and "tbl_shop_category" each shop can be in multiple category. Following is a table structure.

1) tbl_shop

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shop_name      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_limit | int(11)      | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2) tbl_shop_category

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shop_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to fetch all shops with their categories with limit define in tbl_shop table in column category_limit

e.g.

if Shop name "Mysha" has 20 categories in tbl_shop_category and has category_limit of 5 in tbl_shop table then it should return only 5 categories for that shop.

I tried following query but not getting result as I want.

```
SELECT    shop.shop_name,
          cat.category
FROM      tbl_shop shop
LEFT JOIN tbl_shop_category cat
ON        shop.id = cat.shop_id
LIMIT     shop.category_limit;
```

Comment: I dont understand your database design or better the reason for that redundant design. You have the same table 2 times. You dont need that.

Comment: sorry my bad. check updates.

Comment: what is your output even if its the wrong one